# How do I pass in empty values in Fitnesse test?

Tags: c#, .net, fitnesse

I'm using Fit/Fitnesse.  I have a column fixture that looks like this.

```
!|Get Stepstools Medication Id From Vocab and String|  
|Concept As String|Vocabulary Name Abbr|Vocabulary Concept Id|Stepstools Med Id?|  
|AMOXICILLIN|RXNORM|723|1|  
|AMOXICILLIN| | |1|  
|AUGMENTIN|RXNORM|151392|8|  
|AUGMENTIN| | |8|  
|Amoxicillin 1000 MG / Clavulanate 62.5 MG Extended Release Tablet| | |8|
```

I'm trying to pass in empty string values by using `| |` but the test, when I run it, takes the value from the previous row and uses that instead.

My fixture code looks like this:

```
public class GetStepstoolsMedicationIdFromVocabAndString: ColumnFixture
{
    public string VocabularyNameAbbr;
    public string VocabularyConceptId;
    public string ConceptAsString;

    public string StepStoolsMedId()
    {
        MedicationMapping mapping = MedicationMapper.GetStepMedIdFromVocabNameIdAndStringMed(
            VocabularyNameAbbr, 
            VocabularyConceptId, 
            ConceptAsString
            );

        if (mapping.SuccessfullyMapped)
        {
            return mapping.StepstoolsMedicationId.ToString();
        }
        else 
        {
            return mapping.ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the test to use the empty string values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it.  Instead of using just "||" or even "| |", Fitnesse expects the keyword "blank" if an empty string is the intent.  So the revised test looks like this:

> !|Get Stepstools Medication Id From Vocab and String|
>   |Concept As String|Vocabulary Name Abbr|Vocabulary Concept Id|Stepstools Med Id?|
>   |AMOXICILLIN|RXNORM|723|1|
>   |AMOXICILLIN|blank|blank|1|
>   |AUGMENTIN|RXNORM|151392|8|
>   |AUGMENTIN|blank|blank|8|
>   |Amoxicillin 1000 MG / Clavulanate 62.5 MG Extended Release Tablet|blank|blank|8|

Comment: Another useful keyword is `null` for setting an input to null, as opposed to setting it to an empty string, which is what `blank` does.